# Malformed dates entered in database

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am using the following date code to format the date from dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. But for some days I mistakenly used the following code in production:

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        java.util.Date utilDate = format.parse("22-10-2016 00:00:00");
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        System.err.println(sqlDate);
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }
```

which gives date as `0028-04-07`.

So now in my case I have around 300 entries which are malformed due to it, is there any way get the correct date back?

I have seen the pattern followed by dates:

```
23-10-2016 --> 0029-04-07
24-10-2016 --> 0030-04-08
25-10-2016 --> 0031-04-08
26-10-2016 --> 0032-04-07
```

So working on it till someone helps.

Comment: I'm afraid that your year may have been truncated before you inserted it into your table.  In this case, it may not be possible to reconstruct the original value.  You might want to replace the bad dates manually.

Comment: There is no problem of truncated year because I will consider it 2016, so would I able to retrieve the month and date?

Comment: Perhaps...try cleaning up the data if you can

Comment: Have a look at this : [Java – How to get current date time](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/)

Comment: Try to do the other way. I mean `format.format()` instead of `format.parse()` to get back  the original date. . But I am afraid it may not work as there is a complexity as you have used sql Date too.

Answer (score 2):

I am optimistic about what the solution provides.
It may not be clear to you, but by putting 2016 in the days, Java automatically rolled it forward.  So where your year would have been 23, it's been pushed forward nearly 6 years.
I think this sample code, will get you quite a ways.  I'm banking on the idea that, since this is a support issue and not going unnoticed for very long, it only affects 2016.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date utilDate = format.parse("0030-04-07");
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(utilDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -(2016-1));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        Date time = cal.getTime();
        System.err.println(time);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
        time = cal.getTime();
        System.err.println(sqlDate);
        System.out.println(time);


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```